# When is the sum of divisors a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-sum

> Can we efficiently figure out when the sum of divisors of a number can be a prime?

I realized that this can be possible only when the number is expressible as a power of only one prime, e.g. $n = p^\alpha$. Now, the sum of divisors is $ 1+p+p^2+p^3+ \ldots + p^\alpha$. Now the  problem is to figure out when this summation could be prime. How do we go about it?

Comment: I don't think you'll have much luck here, with $p=2$ you get the Mersenne primes for example

Comment: And when $\alpha=2$ you're asking for primes of the form $p^2+p+1$, another notorious open problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is sequence [A023194 of OEIS](https://oeis.org/A023194) ($\sigma_1$ is the [divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)).

Not much seems known except that all solutions except $n=2$ may be written as $\ n=p^{2m}$ and have a prime number of divisors (i.e. $2m+1$ is prime).

Sorry if this doesn't help,

Comment: Thanks, that did help. Am I right in saying that we will not be able to predict in constant time if the sum of the divisors of a number going to be prime or not?

Comment: @nonChun: since your list includes the [Mersenne primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) as pointed out by Cocopuffs (see too Gerry's example) you'll need at least a method as efficient as proving primality of these. This doesn't imply that a 'constant time method' doesn't exist but at least that none seems known !

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the divisors of $2^{x-1}$ is $2^x-1$, a Mersenne number. Thus, 
only powers of two (not all) can be the answer candidates for the question. The well-known Lucas test can be used to verify the primeness of $2^x-1$. It has 
been conjectured that there exist infinitely many Mersenne primes. But, the answer to this question is still not known to date.

Comment: Not only powers of two can be candidates, $1 + 3 + 3^2 = 13$